# include_once failed to open stream and Warning: include_once(): Failed opening.for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')

Tags: php, apache, require, require-once, include-once

I am getting below error . I have already tried with **dir** , document root, require_once and require.

This error i am getting in Live Server.

```
Warning: include_once(/storage/ssd1/655/2980655/public_html/Lib/DB//MysqliDb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd1/655/2980655/public_html/index.php on line 8

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/storage/ssd1/655/2980655/public_html/Lib/DB//MysqliDb.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd1/655/2980655/public_html/index.php on line 8
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: `(/storage/ssd1/655/2980655/public_html/Lib/DB//MysqliDb.php)` have seen the double `//` before `Mysqlidb.php` file.

Comment: Its Still giving issue .

Comment: why don't you try with `/home/public_html/Lib/DB/MysqliDb.php`

Comment: Still getting the same error.    
Warning: require_once(/home/public_html/Lib/DB/MysqliDb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd1/655/2980655/public_html/index.php on line 8

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/public_html/Lib/DB/MysqliDb.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd1/655/2980655/public_html/index.php on line 8

Comment: then might be something typo mistake you are doing

Comment: Found solution. Case sensitive . Thank you!!!

Comment: see i have already told you that there might be a typo mistake